# Setting conditions for a scikit learn agglomerative clustering algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I've used an agglomerative clustering algorithm to cluster a 51x56 dataset. The algorithm works, but I want to add a condition for the clustering. For datapoints to be put in the same cluster, I need the values in a particular column to be identical.

```
z=df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None,distance_threshold=(10), affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(z)
```

z is a factorized dataframe. A part of this dataframe is shown below.

```
0       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
1       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
2       0       0       0       0  ...        1       -1       -1          -1
3       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
4       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
5       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
6       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
7       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
8       0       0       0       0  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
9       0       0       0       0  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
10      0       1       1       1  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
11      0       1       1       1  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
12      0       2       1       2  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
13      0       2       1       2  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
14      0       3       1       3  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
15      0       3       1       3  ...       -1       -1       -1          -1
16      1       4       1       4  ...        0       -1       -1          -1
17      1       4       1       4  ...        1       -1       -1          -1
```

Let's say that column 3 is the column I want to specify my condition for. So what I currently get, for example, is that row 9 and 10 are put into the same cluster. But looking at their values in column 3, you can see that row 9 has a value of 0 and row 10 a value of 1. I want a code that only allows them to be put into the same cluster if these values are idnetical, regardless whether this value is 0 or 1 or any other number.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using clustering algorithm, but just grouping values by specific column:

```
df.groupby('column_name')
```

Then, if you want smaller clusters, you can use a clustering algorithm for each group.